# How to call a variable ($name) inside PHP Array?

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to sharpen my PHP skills, but am at a loss when it comes to arrays.

Here's the deal:
I'm trying to set the value of a form element to be $emx - a variable that catches a parameter from a URL string i.e. myform.html?emx=youremail@email.com

Here is the array I have, which builds the form (this is PHP Yii)

```
'email' => array('type'=>'text', 'label'=>$this->t('Your email address'), 'value' => $emx, 'onFocus' => 'this.value=""'),
```

The HTML that it produces:

```
<input type="text" id="MDealSubscribeForm_email" name="MDealSubscribeForm[email]" onfocus="this.value=&quot;&quot;" value="">
```

I have defined $emx as the following:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['emx'] != ""){
    $emx = $_GET['emx'];}
    else {
    $emx = "Enter your email address";} ?>
```

The problem I'm having is that the value is not being set to $emx - regardless of it I append ?emx= to the URL or not, value is always ""

UPDATE: The php for if ($_Get['emx']... is in one file (a wrapper) and the 'email' => array(... is in a separate file - if that matters.

Do I have the array syntax wrong?  I thought I'd simply need to put in $emx to set the value.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: You forgot to mention the question / problem you are having.

Comment: Syntax looks OK... I find it best to use `isset($_GET['emx'])`. Right before you make that array, `var_dump($emx);` to see what it is.

Comment: @PeeHaa i assume value should be populated with what was in $emx

Comment: print_r($array); <<or what ever the array is called

Comment: @PeeHaa Trying to populate it with whatever $emx is (either the email or the string Enter your email address)

Comment: var_dump($emx) resulted in: string(24) "Enter your email address".  This was expected as I did not add ?emx to the URL

Comment: @Dagon print_r($emx) results in "1"

Comment: @Dagon Thats true, but I never named the array. Is this an issue of globals? I can do var_dump and see the correct string was set as $emx but when setting value= to $emx, it is blank

Answer (score 1):

`MDealSubscribeForm`  is the model you are using to build your form (I am calling it as `$model` in my answer )

```
if(isset($_GET['emx'])){
    $model->email = $_GET['emx'];
} else {
    $model->email = "Enter your email address";
}
```

remove `'value' => $emx` , this is not needed anymore.

--

and also, try `'onFocus' => 'js:this.value=""'` and I believe this will give correct html instead of `&quot;&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$_GET['MDealSubscribeForm']['email']` (if it's a GET)

Next time just do a `print_r($_GET);` to debug forms

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm grabbing the email from the URL fine. I'm just unable to get it to show for value= in the form, which is built by the array.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use a placeholder attribute on the email input field, rather than explicitly setting a value if the email is not set. I always hate seeing inline javascript.

Try:

```
<?php $emx = (isset($_GET['emx'])) ? $_GET['emx'] : ''; ?>
```

and then:

```
'email' => array('type'=>'text', 'label'=>$this->t('Your email address'), 'value' => $emx, 'placeholder' => 'Enter your email address'),
```

Back on topic, this does not look like an array designed for the standard Yii form input generator function. Maybe the problem is in the code that converts this array to the input HTML? Can you tell us or show us the code that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a lot of wrong answers because you thought this was a PHP question and titled your question as so.  From everything you've said, it looks likes `$emx` is set properly, the trouble is that you can't get it to show in the Yii generated form.

Note that there is no 'value' property for a [CFormInputElement](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormInputElement).  To set the value, you need to set it in your model, e.g.:

```
$model->email = $emx;
```

You could also avoid the `else` statement, [by setting the `default` value in your model or the form](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model).